Can my graphql query to shopify's storefront API search the title of products and also include filtering for available variants
I am using my shopify store to make a mobile app that accesses collections and products via shopify's storefront api. I want to be able to search through products as well as sort and filter them, all in the query itself as client-side filtering messes with pagination. Right now I have one query that works for search, and one for sort/filter, but want to get one that works for all. The search one queries products and therefore uses the query: parameter, whereas the sort/filter one queries collections and therefore uses the filters: parameter.
This is my current search query:
export const getProductsQuery =
(next: number | string | null, query: string | null, sortKey: string | null, reverse: boolean | null) =>
JSON.stringify(
{query:
`query getProducts($next: String, $query: String, $sortKey: ProductSortKeys, $reverse: Boolean {
    products(first: 40, after: $next, query: $query, sortKey: $sortKey, reverse: $reverse) {
     edges {
          cursor
          node {
              id
              createdAt
              title
              featuredImage {
                  url
              }
              priceRange {
                maxVariantPrice {
                    amount
                }
              }
              compareAtPriceRange {
                maxVariantPrice {
                  amount
                }
              }
              variants(first: 8) {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                    availableForSale  
                    selectedOptions {
                      value
                    }
                     storeAvailability: metafield(namespace: "custom", key: "availability") {
                      key
                      value
                     } 
                  }
                }
              }
              colors: metafield(namespace: "custom", key: "colors") {
                value
              } 
              set: metafield(namespace: "custom", key: "products_in_set") {
                value
              }
              colorVariations: metafield(namespace: "product", key: "variations") {
                value
              }
              variationColor: metafield(namespace: "product", key: "variation_name") {
                value
              }
              colorOptions: metafield(namespace: "product", key: "variation_colors") {
                value
              }
          }
      }
      pageInfo {
          hasNextPage
          hasPreviousPage
      }
  }
}`, variables: { next, query, sortKey, reverse } })

the query parameter can look something like this:
query": "title:Ayla* AND variantOption:value:1X AND metafield:custom:colors:value:pink"

and properly search for the name Ayla, in products that have a variantOption 1X and are pink. Even if I add AND available_for_sale:true, I cannot get only products that are available in variantOption 1X. I want to sort for available sizes, but since the sizes are variants and I cannot query on variantMetafields, this does not seem to be an option.
Separately, I have this query working for sort/filter:
export const getProductsByCollectionQuery =
(next: number | string | null, collectionId: string | null, sortKey: string | null, reverse: boolean | null, filters: any | null) =>
JSON.stringify({
  query: `query getProductsByCollection($next: String, $collectionId: ID!, $sortKey: ProductCollectionSortKeys, $reverse: Boolean, $filters: [ProductFilter!]) {
    collection(id: $collectionId) {
      products(first: 40, after: $next, sortKey: $sortKey, reverse: $reverse, filters: $filters) {
        edges {
          cursor
          node {
            createdAt
            id
            title
            featuredImage {
              url
            }
            priceRange {
              maxVariantPrice {
                amount
              }
            }
            compareAtPriceRange {
              maxVariantPrice {
                amount
              }
            }
            variants(first: 8) {
              edges {
                node {
                  id
                  availableForSale  
                  selectedOptions {
                    value
                  }
                   storeAvailability: metafield(namespace: "custom", key: "availability") {
                    key
                    value
                   } 
                }
              }
            }
            colors: metafield(namespace: "custom", key: "colors") {
                value
            } 
            set: metafield(namespace: "custom", key: "products_in_set") {
                value
            }
            colorVariations: metafield(namespace: "product", key: "variations") {
              value
            }
            variationColor: metafield(namespace: "product", key: "variation_name") {
              value
            }
            colorOptions: metafield(namespace: "product", key: "variation_colors") {
              value
            }
          }
        }
        pageInfo {
          hasNextPage
          hasPreviousPage
        }
      }
    }
  }
`,
  variables: { next, collectionId, reverse, sortKey, filters }
})

where a sample filters parameter might look like this:
filters= [{"variantOption": {"name": "size", "key": "XL"}}, {"variantMetafield": {"key": "availability", "namespace": "custom", "value": "In Stock"}}, {"price": {"max": 250, "min": 0}}]
Here, the filters properly filter out products where the selected variant (XL) is not available specifically. The problem with this query is that I cannot query for title. I considered adding the title to a metafield and querying for that metafield, but I cannot seem to check anything except an exact string match whereas i want to see if the product name contains the search term. I also am considering adding another metafield to products so that here i can return all products that contain the words being searched for, by making the metafield a list of words. this seems convoluted and a bit hack-y, but I am not sure if there is a way otherwise. I would prefer to have this query work for both, but am just hoping to get them working regardless.
